# What would make XMLReader usable via command line `php` but not Apache?

Tags: php, apache, xmlreader

Even the simplest PHP script I try to write, if I try to use XMLReader, will fail if I try and run it through localhost:

**xml.php:**

```
<?php $xmlReader = new XMLReader(); ?>
```

**result (apache2/error.log):**

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'XMLReader' not found in /var/www/html/xml.php:1
```

If I run the same script as above via the command line, `php xml.php`, there's no problem whatsoever. The XML library shows up in `phpinfo()`, and I'm told that PHP 7.2 doesn't have that flag that disables XMLReader (it stopped being default in 5.x). What else could be causing a breakdown?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, if that matters.

Comment: There's a different `php.ini` for CLI and webserver.

Comment: It wasn't the source of my misery this time, but I imagine it will catch me in the future. I'll keep that in mind, going forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had just installed `php-xml`, **I had to restart my Apache service** so that it could see the library:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The command line was working because it was restarting with each call.

Always remember to restart your local server after installing vital components!